# *a++ = *b++ (what does it mean, how it works)

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

What would be the values after performing this operation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int *a = 0;
    int *b = 3;
    *a++ = *b++;
    printf("%d", a);
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: `int *a = 0;` isn't the same as `int *a; *a = 0;`. The former declares a pointer and sets it to 0 (the pointer, not the pointed value!), making it an invalid pointer. The latter declares a pointer and then tries to dereference it, assigning the value 0 to the pointed value. This is still wrong, because this way you dereference `a` without having initialised it. You probably want something like `int value_a = 0; int *a = &value_a; int value_b = 3; int *b = &value_b;` and then `a` and `b` are valid pointers.

Comment: @YellowKing0907,  What did you expect `int *b = 3;` to do?

Answer (score 5):

> `*a++ = *b++` (what does it mean, how it works)

```c
*a++ = *b++;
```

means

```c
*(a++) = *(b++);
```

`x++` increments `x` and returns the original value. So the following is equivalent:

```c
*a = *b;     // Copy the `int` to which `b` points into the `int` to which `a` points.
a = a + 1;   // Make `a` point to the following `int`.
b = b + 1;   // Make `b` point to the following `int`.
```

```
Before:                                     After:

a                                           a
+----------+        +----------+            +----------+        +----------+
|        ---------->| x        |            |        ------+    | p        |
+----------+        +----------+            +----------+   |    +----------+
                    | y        |                           +--->| y        |
                    +----------+                                +----------+
                    |          |                                |          |


b                                           b
+----------+        +----------+            +----------+        +----------+
|        ---------->| p        |            |        ------+    | p        |
+----------+        +----------+            +----------+   |    +----------+
                    | q        |                           +--->| q        |
                    +----------+                                +----------+
                    |          |                                |          |
```

---

> The code above gives me a segmentation fault.

You assigned garbage to `a` and `b`. `0` as a pointer is the NULL pointer, and `3` isn't a valid pointer.

Comment: So, suppose a points to an integer value of 0, and b points to an integer value of 5, what would be the updated values after the operation?

Comment: The integer to which `a` used to point will be `5` (the value of the integer to which `b` used to point).

Comment: So, is it just a copy operation to copy the original value pointed by b to a?

Comment: No, as shown in my answer, it also changes `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int *a = 0;
    int *b = 3;
    *a++ = *b++;
    printf("%d", a);
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

the printed values can not be predicted as the code invokes undefined behavior in multiple ways.

First, both `*a` and `*b` invoke undefined behavior by dereferencing invalid pointers - `a` is initialized to a null pointer value, and `b` is initialized to point to address `3`, which is almost certainly invalid also.

Second,`printf("%d", a);` invokes undefined behavior by trying to print an `int *` variable with the `%d` format specifier for `int`.  The proper code would be

```
printf("%p", ( void * ) a);
```

It's not clear what the currently-posted code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Mmmm. But the original question doesn't show the initialization of either a or b. Coming up with an invalid code snippet for an incomplete question doesn't see all that helpful (or difficult). Furthermore, this is _exactly_ how GCC implements memcpy... :p  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/memcpy.c

Comment: @enhzflep **Read the edit history** before you make specious claims.  The code in this answer is **quoted** from the original version of the question.  The OP defaced the question.

Comment: defaced/edited/altered... Which definition is correct is open to interpretation. Your answer may well have been correct when you provided it (read: was). My comment seems to be in the same boat. Feel free to edit your answer to repel the downvote.